# Prevent unknown nodes joining cluster

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I am new to Cassandra. When i tried to set up a Cassandra cluster, i noticed that any node can join the cluster if it has the IP address of seed nodes, then your data can be seen by any one. How to prevent this? (i thought about requiring password before joining but don't know how to do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use kerberos!! check Datastax documentation - http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise3.0/security/security_setup_kerberos